# execute multiple methods on object creation dynamically

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it is possible to execute a method a dynamic amount of times on creation of an object?

Example:

```
var converter = new StringConverter()
                    .ConvertString("string1")
                    .ConvertString("string2");
```

Is it possible to do this dynamicly with the items from a list?

Example

```
List<string> strings = new List<String>();

var converter = new StringConverter()
                    foreach(var item in strings)
                    {
                       .ConvertString(item)
                    };
```

I don't want to create the Object first and then execute the methods the given amount of times.

I came across this problem and was able to solve it in a different way. But I'm wondering if this is even possible this way.

Thanks in advance

I tried different ways of the code above, but nothing worked

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me just yet. Is this `StringConverter` a custom class of yours? Where do the results of the `ConvertString` methods go?

Comment: Assuming `ConvertString` could be made static and returns the result of the conversion, you could maybe do `var converted = strings.Select( s => StringConverter.ConvertString(s) ).ToList();` (Not an answer, because I am making bold assumptions, here)

Comment: String converter is no real class, just an example. I came across some code, where a method of a class was executed multiple times with different parameters on creation of the object, like in the first example. Lets say Convert string converts a string and adds it to a list of strings in the converter object. I was wondering if I can call the ConvertString method a dynamic amount of times on the creation of the object. The Amount of calls depends on the amount of objects in a list or Array like in a foreach. ConvertString is not static.

Comment: Fluent API is not really the thing you want to use, when you process "for each element in a list". Except you have an overload that takes a list and does its thing for each element in it.

Comment: See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface